# How to share photos to Twitter app from my app?

Tags: ios, image, twitter

I build an app, when I share photos to Twitter app from my app (by IOS shared-button), it can only display links, I would like to be a display Picture. How can I achieve it?

Comment: The twitter API would tell you better. The question is too broad for this site.

Comment: Thanks. I  think a specific link format can make sharing to Twitter to display a picture, is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this first you need to import Social framework

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    if (composeViewController) {
        [composeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image"]];
        [composeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"]];
        NSString *initialTextString = @"Tour Tweet";
        [composeViewController setInitialText:initialTextString];
        [composeViewController setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                NSLog(@"Posted");
            } else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Post Cancelled");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Post Failed");
            }
        }];
        [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Please go through https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/ for more information about SLComposeViewController

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can easily share photo on twitter from your app. and you can also access other options of twitter.

https://github.com/ronaldwang/FHSTwitterEngine